# Semi-direct v.s. Direct products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product, direct-product

What is the difference between a direct product and a semi-direct product in group theory?

Based on what I can find, difference seems only to be the nature of the groups involved, where a direct product can involve any two groups and the semi-direct product only allows a normal subgroup $N$ of some group $G$ and another subgroup of $G$ that intersects trivially with $N$.

Is this all? What are the significance? Thank you.

Comment: You can define an "external" semidirect product that has as input two groups $G, H$ and a homomorphism $\phi : G \to \text{Aut}(H)$ ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Semidirect_products_and_group_homomorphisms ). It reduces to a direct product if $\phi$ is trivial, so direct products are a special case of semidirect products.

Comment: Direct product of Abelian groups ia always abelian while even semi direct product of cyclic groups need not be abelian. Is this significant enough?

Comment: In the direct product of $H$ and $K$, elements $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ commute, so $kh = hk$.  In the semidirect product, we have $kh = \varphi(h)k$ for some automorphism $\varphi$ of $h$.  Thus, as Qiaochu mentioned, we need a homomorphism from $K$ into $Aut(H)$ in order to make this action make sense.  If that homomorphism is trivial, we have $kh = \varphi(h)k = hk$ and therefore have the direct product.

Comment: @Carl: Thank you. Isn't the direct product of the form $(h,k)\in H\times K$ so that the $h$'s and $k$'s are separated? But then how can they commute?

Comment: @retro: Note that in $H\times K$, elements of the form $(h,1)$ and $(1,k)$ commute with each other.  You identify $H$ with the subgroup $H\times 1 \le H
\times K$, and similarly $K$ with $1 \times K$ and see that elements in those subgroups commute with elements in the other.  Conversely, if you have a group written $G$ where each element is written uniquely in the form $hk$, and $hk = kh$, then $G\cong H \times K$

Comment: @Carl: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks.

Comment: @KannappanSampath: Yes, it is significant enough :) Thanks.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Let's look at three related concepts, in increasing order of complexity:

1. **Direct products.** We say that $G$ is (isomorphic to) a direct product of $M$ and $N$ if and only if there exist subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ such that:

   - $H\cong M$ and $K\cong N$;
   - $H\triangleleft G$ and $K\triangleleft G$;
   - $H\cap K=\{e\}$;
   - $G=HK$.
2. **Semidirect products.** We say that $G$ is (isomorphic to) a semidirect product of $M$ *by* $N$ if and only if there exist subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ such that:

   - $H\cong M$ and $K\cong N$;
   - $H\triangleleft G$;
   - $H\cap K=\{e\}$;
   - $G=HK$.
3. **Extensions.** We say that $G$ is (isomorphic to) an extension of $M$ by $N$ if and only if there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that

   - $H\cong M$;
   - $H\triangleleft G$;
   - $G/H\cong N$.

1 and 2 look very similar. In fact, 1 is a special case of 2 (when $K$ is normal); and 2 is a special case of 3: if $G=HK$, $H\triangleleft G$, and $H\cap K=\{e\}$, then $K$ maps isomorphically onto $G/H$ via the natural projection (the intersection with the kernel is trivial, so the projection restricted to $K$ is one-to-one; and every element of $G$ can be written as $x=hk$ with $h\in H$ and $k\in K$, so $Hx = Hk$, hence the map is onto when restricted to $K$).

But each one is a more general construction than the previous one, yielding more general types of groups.

For instance, in Direct Products, the conditions immediately imply that elements of $H$ commute with elements of $K$:

**Lemma.** Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of $G$. If $H\cap K=\{e\}$, then $hk=kh$ for all $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.

*Proof.* Consider $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}$. Since $K$ is normal in $G$, then 
$$hkh^{-1}k^{-1} = (hkh^{-1})k^{-1} \in (hKh^{-1})K = KK = K;$$
and since $H$ is normal in $G$, then
$$hkh^{-1}k^{-1} = h(kh^{-1}k^{-1}) \in H(kHk^{-1}) = HH = H.$$
Therefore, $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H\cap K = \{e\}$, so $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=e$. Multiplying on the right by $kh$ gives $hk=kh$, as desired. $\Box$

So, for example, if all you know are direct abelian groups, then direct products will only give you abelian groups. If both $M$ and $N$ have exponent $k$, then direct products will give you a group of exponent $k$. (In fact, any *identity* satisfied by both $M$ and $N$ will be satisfied by $M\times N$; but this is perhaps a little advanced for you right now, so don't worry too much about it).

By contrast, semidirect products are more complicated, *because* that second subgroup doesn't have to be normal. The argument above is invalid, and we don't always get that elements of $H$ and elements of $K$ commute (if they *do*, then you have a direct product). The smallest example is $S_3$, the nonabelian group of order $6$ viewed as the permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$, with $M=C_3$, the cyclic group of order $3$, $N=C_2$, the cyclic group of order $2$, and $H=\{I, (1,2,3), (1,3,2)\}$, $K = \{I, (1,2)\}$ (other choices of $K$ are possible).

In a semidirect product, the fact that $H$ is normal means that for every $k\in K$ you have $kHk^{-1}=H$; that is, each $k$ induces an automorphism of $H$. So we can define a homomorphism $K\to \mathrm{Aut}(H)$, by letting $k$ map to the homomorphism $h\mapsto khk^{-1}$. If this map is trivial, you get the direct product of $H$ and $K$. If the map is not trivial, then you get more interesting groups. Different homomorphisms may lead to nonisomorphic groups, so that now we have to be careful: while there is one and only one way to construct a "direct product" of two groups $M$ and $N$, there may, in general, be *many* (non-equivalent) ways of constructing semidirect products of $M$ by $N$.

Note that it is now possible to have a semidirect product of abelian groups that is not abelian (as in the $S_3$ example). And it is no longer true that if both $M$ and $N$ are of exponent $k$, then a semidirect product will also have exponent $k$. For example, take $M=C_2\times C_2 = \{1,x\}\times\{1,x\}$, which is of exponent $2$, take $N=\{1,n\} = C_2$, also of exponent $2$, and let the nontrivial element of $N$ act on $M$ by the rule $n^{-1}(a,b)n = (b,a)$. Then $(x,1)n$ has order $4$:
$$\begin{align*}
\bigl((x,1)n\bigr)^2 = (x,1)n(x,1)n &= (x,1)(n^{-1}(x,1)n) = (x,1)(1,x) = (x,x)\\
\bigl((x,1)n\bigr)^3 = (x,x)(x,1)n &= (1,x)n\\
\bigl((x,1)n\bigr)^4 = (1,x)n(x,1)n &= (1,x)(n^{-1}(x,1)n) = (1,x)(1,x) = (1,1).
\end{align*}$$

Extensions are even more complex: in essence, every finite group can be viewed as a sequence of extensions of simple groups (hence, in part, the interest in classifying all finite simple groups). Not every extension is a semidirect product (or a direct product). For example, $\mathbb{Z}_4$, the cyclic group of order $4$, is an extension of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$: the subgroup $H=\{\overline{0},\overline{2}\}$ is cyclic of order $2$ and normal, and the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_4/H$ is of order $2$, hence cyclic of order $2$. If it were a semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$, then being abelian it would necessarily be a *direct* product, and so would have exponent $2$; so it cannot be written as a semidirect product.

As I mentioned, every group can be expressed as a sequence of extensions using simple groups. By the [Jordan-Hölder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan-H%C3%B6lder_theorem#Uniqueness%3a_Jordan.E2.80.93H.C3.B6lder_theorem), although the sequence is not unique, the precise simple groups that occur *is* (counting multiplicity).

The definitions look quite similar: we just drop the condition of normality for *one* factor when going from direct product to semidirect product; we just exchange "there is a subgroup isomorphic to $N$ that maps isomorphically onto the quotient" with "the quotient is isomorphic to $N$" in going from semidirect product to extension. But the consequences of these "little changes" is large. Much like the difference between "finite abelian group" and "finite group" looks very small (just a single line dropped), but the implications in our ability to classify/understand the objects in question are enormous.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the very detailed explanation!!

Comment: @Arturo, Is there a general expression for the exponent of the semidirect product?

Comment: Fantastic. Great... Thanks for this impressive answer...

Comment: Shouldn't $G$ be an extension of $N$ by $M$ in 3?

Comment: @user92156: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64573/history-of-the-vocabulary-for-group-extensions/64580#64580

Comment: It would help to include how they're denoted in your definitions.

Comment: @Shaun: Sorry, but what are you talking about? I **do** say what I mean; I'm including the definition of "extension of $M$ by $N$" as I use the term. So what exactly is it you want me to include beyond exactly the definition I am using?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No, I mean perhaps you could include some standard notation, like $\times$ for the direct product.

Comment: @Shaun: The standard notation is for external constructions (external direct product, external semidirect product), not for internal ones; and extensions have no standard notation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Where do internal direct products fit into your definitions? Are they included in direct products (first definition)?

Comment: @Junglemath: The definition given under "direct products" **is** the definition of an internal direct product of $H$ and $K$. The distinction is, ultimately, utterly useless. Internal direct products and external direct products are naturally isomorphic.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: By assumptions in 1 of your answer, does $G=HK$ isomorphic to $K\times H$?

Comment: @C.F.G. Of course; because $H\cong M$ and $K\cong N$, so $H\times K\cong M\times N$.

Comment: What do you mean, G=HK? Is it 'for all $h\in H$ and $k \in K$, $h k $ produces all G?' or is it 'for all $h\in H$ and $k \in K$, $h k$ AND $k h$ produce all G?'

Comment: @MondoDuke: Exactly what it says: that the group $G$ is equal to the set $HK=\{hk\mid h\in H,k\in K\}$. What is unclear about that? Neither of the things you write makes any sense whatsoever: they are both utterly nonsensical.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin does that imply that if H and N form a semidirect product, then N and H form one too (in the same order)? Also I think you answered all I needed to know with that comment, thanks. Sorry for being nonsensical. But you do realize that G=HK is a complete shorthand, and its not obvious that the definition with a set you gave is the one used, right?

Comment: @MondoDuke: The definition has **four** parts. To talk about the semidirect product of $H$ *by* $K$, you need $H$ to be a normal subgroup and $K$ to be a subgroup. To talk about the semidirect product of $K$ by $H$ you need $K$ to be a normal subgroup and $H$ to be a subgroup. Why would that imply that if you can form the semidirect product of $H$ by $K$, then you can also form the semidirect product of $K$ by $H$? Why do you think you can just ignore a condition (normal subgroup)?

Comment: @MondoDuke: "But you do realize that $G=HK$ is a complete shorthand and its[sic] not obvious that the definition with a set you gave is the one used, right?" No, **wrong**. It is **standard notation**. If you don't know it, then it's because you don't know standard notation, not because it is not obvious. And even if you don't know standard notation, what you wrote was *utter nonsense*, and that has nothing to with notation;  it has to do with what the words mean.