# Is this a special semidirect product?

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups, semidirect-product, direct-product

Currently I am going through [Representation theory of semi-direct products](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-13/2/281.extract) by Reyes. At the begining of the article, the author defines the semidirect product as follows.

> $G = H \cdot B$ is a semidirect product where $H$ is a normal subgroup
>   of $G$ and $B$ is isomorphic with a group of automorphisms of $H$.

This doesn't match with the definition given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106028/semi-direct-v-s-direct-products) which is:

> **Semidirect products.**
>
> We say that $G$ is (isomorphic to) a semidirect product of $M$ *by*
>   $N$ if and only if there exist subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ such that:
>
> - $H\cong M$ and $K\cong N$;
> - $H\triangleleft G$;
> - $H\cap K=\{e\}$;
> - $G=HK$.

Because, in the second definition $H$ is not required to be isomophic with a group of automorphism of $K$. So, can I say that the first definition is not a general definition of semidirect product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "outer" and "inner" semi-direct products in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

Comment: so it looks, Reyes was talking about the outer semidirect product, right?

Comment: Yes, and the two constructions are closely related.

Comment: could you please explain how they are related?

Comment: A group $G$ is an "inner" semidirect product of $H$ and $K$ if and only if it is isomorphic to an "outer" semidirect product.  "Outer" means giving an actual construction of the semidirect product; "inner" means recognizing it in the wild.

Comment: Also a slight comment on Reyes's line:  when talking about (outer) semidirect products, we need a homomorphism from $K = B$ to $Aut(H)$, but this homomorphism does not need to be injective; i.e. it does not need to identify $K$ as a subgroup of $Aut(H)$.  For example, a direct product $H \times K$ is the case where $K \to Aut(H)$ is the trivial homomorphism.  This is definitely a special case of semidirect products, but it seems like a stretch to call $K$ "isomorphic with a group of automorphisms of $H$" when they all act as the identity.