# Quotient isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Suppose that groups G, H are such that $H \lhd G$, $H \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, and $G / H \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$ for some $n \geq 1$. What then can we say about $G$? I think the only possibilities are that either $G \cong (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^{n+1}$ or $G \cong (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{n-1}$, but I'm not sure how you could prove anything like this.

Comment: Actually, $G$ might not even be abelian. For example take $G=Q$ (the quaternions) and $H=\{1,-1\}$. The quotient is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z})^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $C_2$ for $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ we have a short exact sequence of groups
$$
1\rightarrow C_2\rightarrow G\rightarrow C_2^n\rightarrow 1.
$$
So $G$ is a group extension of $C_2^n$ by $C_2$. This is classified up to equivalence by the second cohomology group $H^2(C_2^n,C_2)$.

The isomorphism classes are "easier" to see.
Indeed, we may have the (semi)direct product if the sequence splits or some other possibilities if it doesn't split. Note that $G$ need not be abelian. Take for example the quaternion group.

Reference: [How to find all possible extensions of a finite group by $C_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64291/how-to-find-all-possible-extensions-of-a-finite-group-by-c-2?rq=1)

Some more details are also given [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/extensions.html), but with $C_2$ and $C_2^n$ interchanged. Nevertheless it is useful.

Comment: Great, thanks for this!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I think the group $G$  is  a direct product of an elementary abelian group with a group $E$, where $E$ is either cyclic of order $4$, an extraspecial group (of which there are two isomorphism types for each order $2^{2k+1}$), or a group of symplectic type (which is a central product of an extraspecial group with cyclic $4$).